# python: replace multiple columns in pandas frame with values form dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'192.168.1.10', '45.7.12.34', 'abc'],[4, '10.10.1.11', '90.90.67.33', 'def'], [77, '52.1.7.90', '67.5.3.5', 'ghi' ], [90, '19.19.90.7', '77.88.99.44', 'xyz']], columns=['A', 'sip', 'dip', 'location'])
addrs = {'192.168.1.10': 'myhost.net', '45.7.12.34': 'myhost-goo.net', '10.10.1.11': 'myhost-foo.net' }`enter code here`

df[['sip','dip']].replace(addrs, inplace=True)
```

This code returns the warning, and in fact it does not replace `dataframe`'s cell values:

> /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4042:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>             method=method)

Python-3.5.2, pandas-0.24.2

Is it not possible to replace values in multiple columns with dictionary values on one call?

Comment: `df[['sip','dip']] = df[['sip','dip']].replace(addrs).copy()`, try to avoid using `inplace=True`, it will probably be deprecated in the future.

Comment: @erfan, thanks Erfan, it answers my question.